# How to run tests on a mountable engine

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, rspec

I just created a mountable engine. The test directory looks somewhat like this:

```
engine_name
 -test
  - dummy
  - test_helper.rb
  - models
    -engine_name
      -- user_test.rb
  etc
```

1. I attempted to call 'rspec' -> didn't work. Error message stated it couldn't find the folder 'spec'
2. I then called 'rspec test' -> it found the directory, but didn't find the test.
3. Found that rspec looks for *_spec.rb files, so I renamed user_test.rb to user_spec.rb
4. rspec then found the file, but it said it couldn't find test_helper.rb (since that was required by user_spec.rb).

I have a feeling that this engine's test directory is not designed for rspec. What's the best way to test an engine?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are using rspec, you should use the directory `spec` instead of `test`.

The `test` directory is the default for test unit.

If you run `rspec` and you have a `spec` directory it will grab the tests from there.

You need a right `spec_helper.rb` (`test_helper.rb` is for test unit). You can see the example of `spec_helper.rb` in the template from `rspec-rails` [repository](https://github.com/rspec/rspec-rails/blob/master/lib/generators/rspec/install/templates/spec/spec_helper.rb.tt).

Then, you should require the `spec_helper` in the `user_spec.rb` and just run `rspec` in the terminal.